# Alternative for @property for Firefox

Tags: css, css-animations

I was working on a circle animation for a project recently and mistakenly used `@property` without knowing that it's only available in certain browsers. I needed this animation to work in all browsers so I was trying to see if there is alternative to this. Here's what I was doing with `@property`:

```js
$('.test').addClass('circle');

var circle = $(".circle");
var change = $(".change");
var circleImg = $('.fade-in-img');

circle.on('animationend', function() {
  $(circleImg).fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.circle-graph-info {
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: 0 0 0 240px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .circle-graph-info p {
        color: #479F56;
        font-size: 120px;
        font-weight: 800;
        margin: 0 -50px 0 0;
        max-width: 275px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .circle-graph-info span {
        color: #000;
        display: block;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: 400;
    }

    .circle-graph-info p:first-of-type::before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        background: #479F56;
        height: 5px;
        left: -200px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        width: 161px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    @property --a {
        syntax: '<angle>';
        inherits: false;
        initial-value: 0deg;
    }

    .circle {
        width: 484px;
        height: 484px;
        padding: 20px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-mask:
            conic-gradient(#000 var(--a), transparent var(--a)),
            linear-gradient(#000, #000) content-box;
        -webkit-mask-composite: source-out;
        mask-composite: subtract;
        background: rgb(138,173,81);
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(138,173,81,1) 0%, rgba(71,159,86,1) 0%, rgba(138,173,81,1) 100%);
        border-radius: 50%;
        animation: progress 2s .3s ease forwards;
        -webkit-animation: progress 2s .3s ease forwards;
    }


    @-webkit-keyframes progress {
        to {
            --a: 360deg;
        }
    }


    .circle-wrap {
        padding: 5px;
        position: relative;
        height: 484px;
        width: 484px;
    }

    .fade-in-img {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 9;
        top: 32%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 140px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .outer-border {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        height: 102%;
        width: 102%;
    }

    .inner-border {
        background: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        top: 32px;
        left: 32px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        height: 89%;
        width: 89%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle-graph">
  <div class="graph-wrap">
    <div id="graph-2">
      <div class="circle-wrap">
      <div class="test"></div>
      <div class="outer-border"></div>
      <div class="inner-border"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've been trying to get this to work without the `@property` part but everything I attempt breaks the animation. I have been trying use

```
from {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
to {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

and

```
0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
```

but these give me very different result:

```js
$('.test').addClass('circle');

var circle = $(".circle");
var change = $(".change");
var circleImg = $('.fade-in-img');

circle.on('animationend', function() {
  $(circleImg).fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.circle-graph-info {
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: 0 0 0 240px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .circle-graph-info p {
        color: #479F56;
        font-size: 120px;
        font-weight: 800;
        margin: 0 -50px 0 0;
        max-width: 275px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .circle-graph-info span {
        color: #000;
        display: block;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: 400;
    }

    .circle-graph-info p:first-of-type::before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        background: #479F56;
        height: 5px;
        left: -200px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        width: 161px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    @property --a {
        syntax: '<angle>';
        inherits: false;
        initial-value: 0deg;
    }

    .circle {
        width: 484px;
        height: 484px;
        padding: 20px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-mask:
            conic-gradient(red, transparent),
            linear-gradient(red, red) content-box;
        -webkit-mask-composite: source-out;
        mask-composite: subtract;
        background: rgb(138,173,81);
        /* background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(138,173,81,1) 0%, rgba(71,159,86,1) 0%, rgba(138,173,81,1) 100%); */
        border-radius: 50%;
        animation: progress 2s .3s ease forwards;
        -webkit-animation: progress 2s .3s ease forwards;
    }

    .reverse-circle {
        animation: reverse-progress 2s .3s ease forwards;
        -webkit-animation: reverse-progress 2s .3s ease forwards;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes progress {
        /* 0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
        100% {transform: rotate(360deg);} */

        from {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        to {
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes reverse-progress {
        to {
            --a: 0deg;
        }
    }

    .circle-wrap {
        padding: 5px;
        position: relative;
        height: 484px;
        width: 484px;
    }

    .fade-in-img {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 9;
        top: 32%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 140px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .outer-border {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        height: 102%;
        width: 102%;
    }

    .inner-border {
        background: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        top: 32px;
        left: 32px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        height: 89%;
        width: 89%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle-graph">
  <div class="graph-wrap">
    <div id="graph-2">
      <div class="circle-wrap">
      <div class="test"></div>
      <div class="outer-border"></div>
      <div class="inner-border"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm honestly stuck and could use a pointer or any help. Can I get what I'm trying to do to even work here or do I need to go in a different direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note you have only specified `@-webkit-keyframes` and not the more standard `@keyframes`, so even if `--property` *was* supported in Firefox, it would not animate.

Regardless, consider using an `<svg>`.

1. Replace the `.test` element with an `<svg>`:

   ```
   <svg width="484" height="484" class="circle">
     <defs>
       <linearGradient id="myGradient" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
         <stop stop-color="rgb(71, 159, 86)" offset="0%"/>
         <stop stop-color="rgb(138, 173, 81)" offset="100%"/>
       </linearGradient>
     </defs>
     <circle
       stroke-width="20"
       stroke="url(#myGradient)"
       fill="none"
       cx="242"
       cy="242"
       r="232"
     />
   </svg>
   ```
2. Make the stroke of the `<circle>` a dash, where the dash is the length of the circumference of the `<circle>`. We do this by setting [`pathLength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength) which translates the circumference to a known number. Then use [`stroke-dasharray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) to set the dash lengths to the same value as `pathLength`:

   ```
   <circle
     …
     pathLength="100"
     stroke-dasharray="100"
     transform="rotate(-90 242 242)"
   />
   ```
3. Adjust the [`stroke-dashoffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dashoffset) so that the default state of the `<circle>`'s dash starts from the blank space between two dashes:

   ```css
   .circle {
     stroke-dashoffset: 100;
   }
   ```
4. Animate the dash in with `animation`:

   ```css
   .circle {
     …
     animation: progress 2s .3s ease forwards;
   }

   @keyframes progress {
     to {
       stroke-dashoffset: 0;
     }
   }
   ```

Live example:

```css
.circle-graph-info {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 0 0 240px;
  position: relative;
}

.circle-graph-info p {
  color: #479F56;
  font-size: 120px;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin: 0 -50px 0 0;
  max-width: 275px;
  position: relative;
}

.circle-graph-info span {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.circle-graph-info p:first-of-type::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: #479F56;
  height: 5px;
  left: -200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 161px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.circle {
  stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  animation: progress 2s .3s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes progress {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

.circle-wrap {
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  height: 484px;
  width: 484px;
}

.fade-in-img {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  top: 32%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 140px;
  text-align: center;
}

.outer-border {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  height: 102%;
  width: 102%;
}

.inner-border {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  left: 32px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  height: 89%;
  width: 89%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-graph">
  <div class="graph-wrap">
    <div id="graph-2">
      <div class="circle-wrap">
        <svg width="484" height="484" class="circle">
          <defs>
            <linearGradient id="myGradient" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
              <stop stop-color="rgb(71, 159, 86)" offset="0%"/>
              <stop stop-color="rgb(138, 173, 81)" offset="100%"/>
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
          <circle
            stroke-width="20"
            stroke="url(#myGradient)"
            fill="none"
            cx="242"
            cy="242"
            r="232"
            pathLength="100"
            stroke-dasharray="100"
            transform="rotate(-90 242 242)"
          />
        </svg>
        <div class="outer-border"></div>
        <div class="inner-border"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is awesome and incredibly detailed! Thanks so much for your help. I have never used SVG's like this before.